# rxswift viewmodel with input output

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, rx-swift, frp

I am trying to achieve something similar in rxswift example project from RxSwift [repo](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxExample/RxExample/Examples/GitHubSignup/UsingDriver/GithubSignupViewModel2.swift). But in my case there are dependent observables. I couldn't find any solution without using binding in viewmodel

Here is the structure of my viewmodel:

First the definitions of input, output and viewmodel

```
typealias UserListViewModelInput = (
    viewAppearAction: Observable<Void>,
    deleteAction: Observable<Int>
)

typealias UserListViewModelOutput = Driver<[User]>

typealias UserListViewModel = (UserListViewModelInput, @escaping UserApi) -> UserListViewModelOutput
```

Then there is actual implementation which doesn't compile.

```
let userListViewModel: UserListViewModel = { input, loadUsers in

    let loadedUserList = input.viewAppearAction
        .flatMapLatest { loadUsers().materialize() }
        .elements()
        .asDriver(onErrorDriveWith: .never())

    let userListAfterDelete = input.deleteAction
        .withLatestFrom(userList) { index, users in
            users.enumerated().compactMap { $0.offset != index ? $0.element : nil }
        }
        .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: [])

    let userList = Driver.merge([loadedUserList, userListAfterDelete])

    return userList
}
```

Viewmodel has two job. First load the user list. Second is delete a user at index. The final output is the user list which is downloaded with `UserApi` minus deleted users.

The problem in here in order the define `userList` I need to define `userListAfterDelete`. And in order to define `userListAfterDelete` I need to define `userList`.

So is there a way to break this cycle without using binding inside view model? Like a placeholder observable or operator that keeps state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for a state machine. What you will see in the code below is that there are two actions that can affect the User array. When the view appears, a new array is downloaded, when delete comes in, a particular user is removed.

This is likely the most common pattern seen in reactive code dealing with state. So common that there are whole libraries that implement some variation of it.

```
let userListViewModel: UserListViewModel = { input, loadUsers in

    enum Action {
        case reset([User])
        case delete(at: Int)
    }

    let resetUsers = input.viewAppearAction
        .flatMapLatest { loadUsers().materialize() }
        .compactMap { $0.element }
        .map { Action.reset($0) }

    let delete = input.deleteAction.map { Action.delete(at: $0) }

    return Observable.merge(resetUsers, delete)
        .scan(into: [User](), accumulator: { users, action in
            switch action {
            case let .reset(newUsers):
                users = newUsers
            case let .delete(index):
                users.remove(at: index)
            }
        })
        .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: [])
}
```

Comment: So the trick is put the all actions that affects the state into scan operator?

Comment: Yes that is the essence of it. This is effectively a Moore State Machine.